# Is #endif GUARD_H good practice?

Tags: c++, directive, conditional-compilation

Consider this:

```
#ifndef GUARD_H
#define GUARD_H
...
#endif GUARD_H
```

rather than:

```
#ifndef GUARD_H
#define GUARD_H
...
#endif // GUARD_H
```

Often I see at the `#endif` an 'identifier' commented out but without commenting it it still works.

Is everything after the `#endif` ingnored or...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not valid C++:  it is ill-formed.  There can be no tokens between the `# endif` and the newline that terminates the preprocessing directive line.

If you want to restate the condition from the `#if` directive, you *can* do so in a comment:

```
#endif // GUARD_H
```

However, this is really just redundant, especially for inclusion guards:  if it's the last `#endif` in a header file, it's almost certainly there to end the `#ifdef` used at the top to prevent multiple inclusion, no?

In other places where you may have multiple nested levels of conditional directives, this *might* be useful, but even then it is often preferable to refactor the code to make it simpler or more straightforward.